# Aligning text with pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

I am trying to align text, one at the extreme left and one at the extreme right as I have shown in the snippet below:

```html
<div>
  <p style="display: flex;">
    <span style="margin-right: auto">At the left</span>
    <span>At the right</span>
  </p>
  <br />
  <p>Some more text</p>
</div>
```

The HTML works fine, but how could I do this with [pdfmake](http://pdfmake.org/#/)? I tried searching but could not find a way to achieve the same with pdfmake.

Answer (score -4):

Alway whenever you generate PDF or email HTML you need to use Table tags

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td width="50%">
      At the left
    </td>
    <td width="50%">
      At the right
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>Some more text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```